# I've lost my MultiBit data, is there a way to access my wallet?

Tags: blockchain, wallet, blockchain.info, multibit, wallet-recovery

I have lost access to my wallet. My hard drive is dead and I don't have access to any backup files. Does `MultiBit` back up everything automatically to the cloud? I know my passcode key and I can see my bitcoins on blockchain.info. I have tried data recovery but the hard drive is not recoverable. I don't know what else to do. Does anyone know how I can regain access to my bitcoins? Appreciate the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say this, but your bitcoin is gone. Without your hard drive, you don't have access to the private keys. You may know the password to decrypt them, but what use is a password without a username?

The best option will be to try and go to a professional data recovery service.

Rule of thumb - Always make backups.

Comment: Is there a way to restore the classic multi-bit wallet with my bitcoin having just my passcode since the wallet words concept didn't exist at the time?

Comment: @southafrica44 no, not possible, the seed phrase is only a representation of your private key. The key itself has always been randomly generated and the seed phrase computed from that. In fact you could have created a seed phrase from your existing key.

Answer (score 0):

if you have enough money on there you can try to have the hard drive saved by a company who can save data from the drive.